# Self charging wood-gas camping stove using thermoelectric module/modules

Tags: generator, peltier

Is it better to string 3 teg thermoelectric generator modules in series to charge 8 NiMH batteries at a current of around 700 mA Delta T of ~80 deg. C or should I use 1 module and try a voltage tripler to get 12-14 Volts and drop the Amperes accordingly? The application is a wood-gas (Little Wolf Energetics) camping stove, harvesting the waste heat from the bottom of the burner unit. I have laid out three modules radially mounted on 5x5" aluminum 1/8" plates above the fan which supplies air to for primary and secondary combustion. This stove may be going to Ethiopia for cooking and charging electronics. Thanks.

Comment: Post diagrams, please.  Otherwise we'll have a difficult time guessing what you have in mind, which increases your odds of getting an incorrect answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can connect the TEGs electrically in series or in parallel. However, if they are not all at the same deltaTemperature, then there will be some inefficiency.

Either method would work, but using a DC/DC converter will allow you to extract some energy from the TEGs at nearly any deltaTemperature;if you just connect in series, and don't use (much) electronics, you'll only deliver power when the TEG voltage is > 12 V, and any V above this is 'wasted'.

Using a boost DC/DC in this type of application isn't trivial if you are trying to extract maximum available power from the TEG. If you are not careful with the control loop, you'll collapse the supply -- need to use MPPT tracking.